# How to write the sql to select the sum from three tables and group by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot-table

I have 3 tables.  `works`,`software`,`agent`

it shows like that:

---

`agent`:

```
id  name
1   agent1
2   agent2
3   agent3
4   agent4
```

`works`

```
id  name    date(TIMESTAMP type)    agent_id
1   w1  2014/1/1    1
2   w2  2014/2/2    1
3   w3  2014/1/3    2
4   w4  2014/1/4    2
5   w5  2014/1/5    3
6   w6  2014/1/6    4
7   w7  2014/1/7    4
8   w8  2014/1/8    4
9   w9  2014/3/9    4
```

`software`

```
id  name    date(TIMESTAMP type)  agent_id
1   s1  2014/1/1    1
2   s2  2014/2/2    1
3   s3  2014/1/3    2
4   s4  2014/1/4    2
5   s5  2014/1/5    3
6   s6  2014/1/6    4
7   s7  2014/1/7    4
8   s8  2014/1/8    4
9   s9  2014/3/9    4
```

---

and I want to get the result like that: get the every month of current year sum of works + software connect by agent_id

```
Jan-14  Feb-14  Mar-14  Apr-14  May-14  Jun-14  Jul-14  Aug-14  Sep-14  Oct-14  Nov-14  Dec-14
agent1  2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
agent2  4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
agent3  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
agent4  6   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

How to write the sql in MySql?

Comment: please post your attempt.

Comment: @MitchWheat actullay, I have no idea on this sql. my first idea maybe `SELECT a.name, FROM agent a, software r, works w where a.id=r.agent_id or a.id=r.agent_id;`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201401 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201401 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jan14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201402 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201402 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201403 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201403 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mar14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201404 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201404 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Apr14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201405 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201405 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS May14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201406 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201406 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jun14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201407 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201407 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jul14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201408 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201408 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Aug14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201409 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201409 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sep14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201410 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201410 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201411 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201411 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nov14, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = 201412 THEN 1 WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = 201412 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dec14
FROM agent a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN works w ON a.id = w.agent_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN software s ON a.id = s.agent_id 
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Comment: I founded some sum result is wrong by this sql. I think the problem in the `left join`. because when I run the simple sql like `SELECT a.id, a.name
,SUM(case WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = '201411' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 201411
FROM agent a LEFT OUTER JOIN works w ON a.id = w.agent_id  GROUP BY a.id order by a.id;`, the result is correct.

Comment: but wrong with sql `SELECT a.id, a.name
,SUM(case WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = '201411' THEN 1  WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = '201411' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 201411
FROM  agent a LEFT OUTER JOIN  works w ON a.id = w.agent_id LEFT OUTER JOIN software s ON a.id = s.agent_id GROUP BY a.id order by a.id;` . do you know why?

Comment: means that the sum from sql with two left join, not equal the sum from software with single left join + sum form works with single left join..

Comment: from this sql. I can get the correct result `select id,name ,sum(`201411`)  from
(
 (SELECT a.id, a.name
 ,SUM(case WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM w.date) = '201411' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 201411
 FROM agent a LEFT OUTER JOIN works w ON a.id = w.agent_id  GROUP BY a.id order by a.id)
 union
 (SELECT a.id, a.name
 ,SUM(case WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.date) = '201411' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 201411
 FROM agent a LEFT OUTER JOIN software s ON a.id = s.agent_id  GROUP BY a.id order by a.id) ) t
group by id;`